# Opening and closing stock

Tags: sql, oracle

I've data as shown in the image and i need opening and closing stock data.

Input_data

```
WAREHOUSECODE   PRODUCT_CODE    STOCK_DATE  QUANTITY    STOCKVALUE_SC
    B12           2210008       31-DEC-17     2.5           10.815
    B12           2210008       31-DEC-17     5             21.63
    B12           2210008       08-JAN-18    -1             -4.326
    B12           2210008       08-JAN-18     1              4.326
    B12           2210008       08-JAN-18    -1             -4.326
```

expected output

```
PRODUCTKEY  WAREHOUSECODE   PRODUCT_CODE    STOCK_DATE  OPENING_STOCK   TRANSACTION_Qty CLOSING_STOCK   
B12-2210008     B12             2210008     31-DEC-17         0              7.5            7.5
B12-2210008     B12             2210008     08-JAN-18         7.5            -1             6.5
```

Thanks for the support.

Regards,
Viresh

Comment: Please review [ask]

Comment: Aron is right. The first version of the question was better (with the data rather than the image). I got to copy the data before you edited and that's why I was able to answer. Nobody wants to copy data out of an image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using SQL Server 2008 R2 or above.

Here's a way to do it using window functions:

```
with raw_data as (
  select
   warehousecode + convert(varchar(10), product_code) as productKey,
   warehousecode,
   product_code,
   stock_date,
   sum(quantity) as transaction_qty
  from Stock
  group by warehousecode, product_code, stock_date
)
select 
  productKey,
  warehousecode,
  product_code,
  stock_date,
  sum(transaction_qty) over (
    partition by productKey
    order by stock_date
  ) - transaction_qty as opening_stock,
  transaction_qty,
  sum(transaction_qty) over (
    partition by productKey
    order by stock_date
  ) as closing_stock
from raw_data
;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29064/12

Comment: Thank you, from next time definitely i will paste the data instead of providing the image. By the way i am using oracle db with SQL Developer IDE. Do i need to make any changes to the script? Thanks.

Comment: @viresh Some changes might be needed. I don't use Oracle and don't know the specific syntax.

Comment: I am able to modify the query and it looks fine. One small modification is required. While calculating the closing_stock, Can i get the closing_stock based on the max stock_date for that particular day instead of showing all the transactions for that particular day. Thank you for all the support.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me how to achieve the above requirement?

Comment: @viresh Can you provide an SQLFiddle with the current progress?

Comment: Hi, you mean the current modified script i am using?

Comment: @viresh An SQLfiddle link like I posted above, containing script and data.